# Python Can't Open Program : Error Load A Component

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to launch a program from my python script, other programs work with no issue as chrome.exe etc... But the program i'm looking to open, i get this error msg:

[image]

When i open it manually (double click) it opens with no error.

Here is my script:

```
import os
try:
    os.startfile(r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\VIP72 Socks Client\vip72socks.exe")
    print('done')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

And here is my path folder:

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use `os.startfile` instead of `os.system`?

Comment: Not really, i just saw it on an old stackover flow question. How can i use os.system

Comment: Same exact way, it just launches the command you specify as argument in a subshell. More info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/)

Comment: @Nastor i tested it on both python and manually on cmd (writing the full path) i got the same error. can't load xxz.dat

Comment: I have no idea how vip72socks works, and what role xxz.dat takes into all of this, so I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: Most probably `vip72socks.exe` is looking for dat file in current directory. Change to that directory before calling `os.startfile`

Comment: @Shiv How can i change to that directory please ? if you can write me the code line, thank you

Comment: Try `os.chdir(r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\VIP72 Socks Client\")` before the startfile line

Comment: @Shiv That worked !! 
I tried it on cmd, i changed path by using cd path , but how can i do it on python please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to the directory of `vip72socks.exe` directory. Following should be the code:

```py
import os

try:
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\VIP72 Socks Client\")
    os.startfile(r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\VIP72 Socks Client\vip72socks.exe")
    print('done')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you Shiv !
Can i please contact you on email or facebook for a small questions. I just want someone to redirect me on how to automate a program (small questions, i know python selenium very well, my questions will be smart and not a lots) thank you

Comment: It is not a good idea to put my email in public over here and I do not even know if it would break terms and conditions of stackoverflow. Go my profile there you will find my website and from there you can find my email.